# How to open and resave every file in a directory using python

Tags: python, linux

I work with a set up in the cloud where the files are deleted after 40 days of no edits. I am looking for a simple way to open and resave every file in a directory. The directory is filled with CSV, py and ipynb files.

I have this basic code so far

```
for fname in glob.glob('data_folder/*.csv'):
    with open(fname,'r') as f:
       # code to read data from the file and manipulate the data
```

I am not exactly sure what the save function under the same name should look like

Comment: Open it in mode `"w"` or `"wr"`, and then try f.write, which is practically saving the file.

Comment: From a shell: `touch foo/*.csv`

Comment: What Shawn said. Should there be too many files for the shell to glob (too many arguments error), use find.  `find /path/to/data_folder -mtime +39 -name \*.csv -exec touch "{}" +` ... run that from cron once a week ;)